# Need some help to interpret error message

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

When I try to update the database with Update-Database -force in Package Manager Console, I get this error message:

```
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint
'FK_dbo.Companies_dbo.Projects_ProjectID' on table 'Companies' may cause
cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE
NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
```

I'm not sure what to do. I understand that is has to be something with a Foreign Key. What action should I do about the ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION?